# function to validate dates using regex in bash

Tags: regex, bash, function, validation, date

I have function like following to be able to validate two dates passed to it:

```
function validate_dates() {
    # validate date format to be yyyy-mm-dd
    local regex="^[[:digit]]{4}-[[:digit]]{2}-[[:digit]]{2}$"
    local dates=( "$1" "$2" )
    printf "%s\n" "${dates[@]}"
    for __date in "$dates"
    do
        echo "$__date"
        [[ $__date =~ $regex ]] || error_exit "One of dates is malformed!" # error_exit is just function helper to exit with message
    done
}
```

However when I call function -

```
validate_dates "2013-05-23" "2014-07-28"
```

I get:

```
2013-05-23
2014-07-28
2013-05-23
One of dates is malformed!
```

Why does it break on correctly formatted date?

Comment: are you sure your code matches your output? The output says "2013-05-23", but you said you called `validate_dates "2013-07-23" "2014-07-23"` (July, not May)

Comment: I corrected values. This is actual run of function. Previously I just hard-typed those dates when calling `validate_dates date1 date2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"^[[:digit]]{4}-[[:digit]]{2}-[[:digit]]{2}$"
```

probably should be:

```
"^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}$"
```

You missed some colons.

Also, `for __date in "$dates"` perhaps should be `for __date in "${dates[@]}"`. `"$dates"` would only expand to the first element of the array.

If you want to have more than just 2 parameters or have variable parameters, change

```
local dates=( "$1" "$2" )
```

to

```
local dates=("$@")
```

My version:

```
function validate_dates {
    local regex='^[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}$'
    printf "%s\n" "$@"
    for __; do
        [[ $__ =~ $regex ]] || error_exit "$__ is an invalid date."
    done
}
```

Comment: Damn colons. And I have overseen that `$dates` too, although I know that, as you can see in `printf` I used it right. Thanks for that `$@`, good to know, although I am now using exclusively two params.

Comment: Welcome. Your can also just omit the optional `()` in your function declaration: `function validate_dates { ...; }`.

Comment: I appreciate your help, and I am learning a lot from you, as you seem to be pretty fast on answering so many of my questions :)

Comment: @konsolebox The `function...` is _bash-ism_. The portable way is without function, only `validate_dates() {`.

Comment: @jm666 Portability is a matter of philosophy. If you're using bash, it's also your option to only care about bash. And I've heard that a lot of times already. No need to remind :)

Comment: @konsolebox sure, but the `name() {` works correctly in bash, so no reason to use the function keyword. ;)

Comment: @branquito Always welcome. Not really. Just someone used to share codes since 2006 :)

Comment: @jm666 Like I've been saying it's a matter of preference :)

Comment: @konsolebox Great, I will use your version, simpler the better. You have chosen that `__` as a variable, it could be anything right? And thats neat not specifying params, so it defaults to `$@`. So as long as you are using `[[` you are protected against word splitting?

Comment: @branquito In many of my scripts, the __ variable is a global reusable variable which any function could use. It's meant to be volatile. I sometimes use it as an iteration variable, and sometimes I use it to get results from a function. You can use another local variable if you like. Yes `[[ ]]` doesn't do word splitting.

Answer (score 1):

Please note you cannot "validate date" using only *regex*. A second pass using `date` might be useful:

```
for __date in "$dates"
do
    echo "$__date"
    { [[ $__date =~ $regex ]] && (date -d "$__date" > /dev/null 2>&1) } ||
       error_exit "One of dates is malformed!" # error_exit is just function helper to exit with message
done
```

Comment: Yes of course, it is just that I don't need that second level of checking, because this is what later gets sent to SQLITE, as a query, and that is what it accepts as a date format. So, no problems there. :)

Comment: actually you are right, I should check for valid date, although sqlite wont raise an error, but just to enforce user to enter date correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` with `-P` makes the regex much easier to read, and you can simplify your function as below:

```
function validate_dates {
        for i in $@; do
                grep -qP '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$' <<< $i ||\ 
                error_exit "One of dates is malformed!"     
        done
}
```